# Operating System vs Monitor

Tags: operating-system

Without going into details, how is a Monitor different from an OS?

I read that first there was Serial Processing in the earlier days, and then Monitors and now OS.

Comment: Looks like I made a terrible mistake somewhere to receive all the down votes. If only I knew what the matter is.

Comment: Most likely you were down voted because people misinterpreted what you meant by "monitor." Technically, what you're talking about is called a "batch monitor", which is very different from monitor means in today's world.

Answer (score 3):

Monitor in this context means Batch Monitor.

In the 1950s - mid 60s, before we had true operating systems, we had Batch Monitors. You would "program" the job onto punch cards and put them on an input queue that the machine would process one by one.

The programmer would sit in front of a monitor, which would display memory dumps, debugging information, etc - it was an incredibly tedious process.

Of course the major drawback of a Batch Monitor is that the CPU was often idle. Because CPU speeds are so much faster than I/O speed, the machine would spend the majority of the time reading in the cards (I/O) while the CPU waited.

Nowadays, modern operating systems can run several processes at once and optimize CPU utilization. When a process on the run queue needs to do I/O, the OS puts it on another queue, and the CPU starts processing the next job. When the I/O is done, that process is moved back to the run queue. This way, the CPU is always doing something.

**Edit:**
After looking up "batch monitor" and not finding many references to it, it seems that it is more commonly referred to as a "batch system" - here's a book for reference; should be able to find a pdf version online:
[Modern Operating Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136006639).

Comment: Upvoted, never knew that there existed a thing called "Batch Monitor". Interesting to know, thanks. +1.